# How to insert text in a line that has an empty line above or below?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have set of coordinates that are randomly separated with an empty line:

```
19.815857300 39.791813400
19.816105700 39.791921800
19.816220800 39.791984600
19.816271400 39.792010000

19.786375895 39.678097997
19.783813875 39.677022719
19.782758486 39.676590122
```

and so on...lot of coordinates :)

I want to insert a specific text at the beginning and at the end of the 1st coordinates set,( first line of the "paragraph").
The same for the last line of each paragraph - different text entry
The coordinates between them, also need another text before and after.

so.. the result I would like to achieve, should be something like

```
BEGIN_SEGMENT  0 50 10 19.815857300 39.791813400 0.00000000 
SHAPE_POINT            19.816105700 39.791921800           0
SHAPE_POINT            19.816220800 39.791984600           0
END_SEGMENT         20 19.816271400 39.792010000 0.00000000

BEGIN_SEGMENT  0 50 10 19.786375895 39.678097997 0.00000000 
SHAPE_POINT            19.783813875 39.677022719           0
END_SEGMENT         20 19.782758486 39.676590122 0.00000000
```

etc..etc..

Any ideas on how this could be done with notepad++ and regular expressions? 
Thanx in advance!

Comment: Use a programming language instead of npp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using python 3.6.

It reads in a file "input.txt" - line by line - until it gets an empty line.
On each start it recreates the file "result.txt".

Each found paragraph is appended to "result.txt" - until done.

Now you just need to get a python environment ;o) and feed it your file.

```
import re
import datetime
import random 

# recreate empty file with timestamp
with open("result.txt","w") as r:
    r.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "\n")

with open("input.txt","r") as f:
    while True:
        paragraph = [] 

        line = f.readline()
        if line == "":
           break # readline always retunrs \n on empty lines until file end reached

        while len(line.strip()) > 0:
            # accumulate lines
            paragraph.append(line.strip())
            line = f.readline()

        if not paragraph:
            continue # jumps back up to while True:

        rv = []
        for idx in range(0,len(paragraph)):
            if idx == 0:
                rv.append("BEGIN_SEGMENT  0 50 " + str(random.randint(1,10000)) + " " + paragraph[idx] + " 0.00000000 " + "\n")
            elif idx != (len(paragraph) - 1):
                rv.append("SHAPE_POINT            " + paragraph[idx] + "           0" + "\n")
            else:
                rv.append("END_SEGMENT         " + str(random.randint(1,10000)) + " " + paragraph[idx] + " 0.00000000" + "\n" + "\n")   

        # append results of paragraph
        with open("result.txt","a") as resFile:
            for line in rv:
                resFile.write(line)

# edited code for random numbers instead of fixed ones
```

Comment: WOW!.. the result is exactly what I wanted!!.. thank you so much Patrick! (no I'm on windows and OSX ;)

Comment: Turns out the the part "BEGIN_SEGMENT 0 50 10" has to be "BEGIN_SEGMENT 0 50" + random number + coordinates . That means that the number 10 must not be a fixed number, rather a random number. The same for the number 20 (END SEGMENT   20). The range could be from 1 to 10000 for example.Is it easy enough for a change in the script? thank you!

Comment: @yanis: You would have to add `import random` at the top, remove `10` and `20` form the string literals (leave the blank before `"`) and add in the random number and another blank like so:  `...<blank after 10 or 20>" + random.randint(1, 10000) + " " + paragr...` - it will distort the whitespace-spacing though (lines get longer if you insert 9999 instead of 10)

Comment: Turns a blank text file.. something I;m doing wrong.. where exactly to place "import random"? I put it at the very beggining after the date import...tried other parts too (sry not an expert with programming languages..lol (the white spaces doesn't matter after  it's done ..begin segment and end segment declares that ;)

Comment: @Yannis edited code above - see if it works. Cant check atm - about 4-5h to go before I can verify it

Answer (score -1):

Not complete - you'll have to adjust the first and last rows by hand.

```
Step 1 end segment-begin segment
FIND:\r\n(\d.*)\r\n\r\n
REPLACE: \r\nEND_SEGMENT\t$1\r\n\r\nBEGIN_SEGMENT\t
Step 2: shape point
FIND: ^(\d.*)$
REPLACE: SHAPE_POINT\t$1
```

Assumes that there will be only one blank line between segments.
You can use https://regexper.com/ to display a diagram of the expressions.